# Raising exception in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Having strange error, rising from function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addAnswer(bodyR VARCHAR, userIdR BIGINT, qId BIGINT)
RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
DECLARE
  ret BIGINT;
  author_idR BIGINT;
    BEGIN 
    author_idR := (SELECT "a"."author_id" FROM "question" "a" WHERE "a"."id"=qId);

    IF (author_idR = userIdR ) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION "Question author and answer author shouldn't match!";
    ENDIF;

    INSERT INTO "answer"("body", "author_id", "created_at", "question_id") VALUES (bodyR, userIdR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, qId);
    ret := LASTVAL();
    RETURN ret;
  END
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error statement I receive:

```
ERROR:  unrecognized exception condition "Question author and answer author shouldn't match!"
CONTEXT:  compilation of PL/pgSQL function "addanswer" near line 9

********** Error **********

ERROR: unrecognized exception condition "Question author and answer author shouldn't match!"
SQL state: 42704
Context: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "addanswer" near line 9
```

Appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Rule of thumb: never use double quotes in SQL - then you wouldn't get into this problem....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not use `"` for stating the exception text. Use `'` instead.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html